# I can't make my first NFT sell

Tags: erc-20

A buyer reached out to me on instagram. Sent me a QR Code. I saw the price. She made the payment to the network. She's clean. I'm clean.

But things get complicated from this situtation: My NFTs are on Windows11, Google Chrome Browser, Metamask Wallet. It's connected with OpenSea.com.

I couldn't remember my password and I opened a new wallet in my iOS iPad. Then scanned the QR code that was sent. The system wanted me to pay 0,5 ETH. I have made an EFT from the local bank account and paid. After that I paid the system 0,5 ETH. But the transaction was rejected "money is in ERC20 right now".

The support answered "you have entered several times and it's blocked". and they sad to me "you have to give 0,25 more". I did that. I scanned the QR code, which the buyer sent again, however the page is falling to "timeout".

What's wrong? I don't get it.

Edit: Thank you. Yes. Unfortunately, it turn out it's a scam. Do you know of any way to get my 0,75 ETH back?

---

Thank you. Yes. Unfortunetly, turn it it's a scam. Do you know any way to get my 0,75 ETH back?

Comment: `Unfortunetly, turn it it's a scam. Do you know any way to get my 0,75 ETH back?` If you have been frauded then it is the matter of your local police to get your money back. It is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a scam, be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Alper.

Sorry to say, but you cannot get funds back once they have left your wallet. Please do not scan unsafe QR codes or open links from unknown sources. You do not have to pay to sell an NFT, the buyer is the one paying the fees.

Here is a guide to follow in the future to help you sell NFTs on Opensea.

https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/360063498333-How-do-I-sell-an-NFT-